# Android retrofit копия запроса

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit2, postman

В андроид(ява) приложение есть запрос (retrofit 2)

```
@POST("mobile/product")
Call<ListResponse<Product>> getProducts(@Body ProductFilter productFilter, @Query("offset") int i, @Query("limit") int i2);
```

Мне требуется сделать такой же запрос только с помощью Postman или просто формы html. С параметрами @Query@("offset"), Query("limit") я разобрался. Ввел их как пара ключ/значения в body а вот как ввести @Body ProductFilter productFilter я не имею понятие. Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: ProductFilter надо в виде json положить в Body

Comment: @ЮрийСПб По какому ключу?

Comment: Создайте новый объект типа ProductFilter, заполните и передавайте его первым параметром в функцию. Body это просто аннотация, помощник для понимания типа параметра.

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov в андроид все хорошо работает. Но мне нужно подделать запрос с помощью postman

Comment: С `Query` вы не разобрались! Пример: `http://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret&color=purple` -  в адресе после `?` вы видите query. Дальше, `ProductFilter` нужно превратить в json-строку и поместить в body целиком, как есть.

Comment: Наверняка у ProductFilter есть функция для сериализации чтобы конвертировать в формат тела запроса. Либо используйте какой-то вспомогательный механизм наподобие трассировки (network tracing) для перехвата. Смотрите документацию и скопируйте её результат во время отладки.